# Is it possible to fetch a yaml config using a variable name from typescript/javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, yaml

Lets say I have a yaml file like this:

country.yaml

```
country:
  India:
    State:"Delhi"
  USA:
    State:"Texas"
```

After I load yaml into my ts code:

```
const variable = fs.readFileSync('./path/country.yaml', 'utf-8');
const v2 = yaml.load(variable);
```

Can I fetch a config value using a variable like this:

```
const y = v2.country.insert-variable.State;
```

Is it possible to insert a variable and fetch config like this? and how?

I tried with no success:

```
const y = v2.country.$(insert-variable).State;
```

and

```
const y = v2.country.{{insert-variable}}.State;
```

Comment: `const variable = 'India'; v2.country[variable].State;` try that